# Is it possible to set the default value on a user lookup to be the logged user?

Tags: custom-object

I have a lookup field of users on the custom object.

Wherein I'm looking to set the field to be the logged on user. once the user clicks the new button.

As Highlighted, I wanted to set that user field by default as logged in user.

Is there any way that we can achieve this functionality?[image]

Comment: Do a search for URL hacking

Comment: Yeah it can be done, but there are several considerations before jumping to that solution. You will need to create a "New" custom button to replace existing "New" button from all places from where a new record can be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do URL hacking by creating a new custom button with label for ex: **New Contact**.

Here is the sample screenshot you can follow. This is an example of detail page button or you can also choose list button accordingly, and this code is helping to create a new contact from account screen and prePopulating the fields. 
[image: Button Override]

**CF00N9000000El6SX** this id is the field id of the field, which you want to pre populate with default value. You can find this id by going to the field detail from custom objects page.

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case&retURL={!Account.Id}&def_account_id={!Account.Id}&save_new_url=/500/e?retURL={!Account.Id}&def_account_id={!Account.Id}&CF00N9000000El6SX={!User.Name}&CF00N9000000El6SX_lkid={!User.Id}
```